# How to change the output location of the excel file in Libxlsxwriter library in c++

Tags: c++, excel, libxlsxwriter

I'm trying to output some data from MySQL to an excel file using libxlsxwriter library in c++. I have a problem in changing the output directory of the excel file. from this code, it saves to the original folder where the .cpp file located. Can anyone tell me a way to change the output location of the excel file.

```
    string na = " Batch Report.xlsx";
    string c = RpotBno + na;
    const char *name = c.c_str();

    lxw_workbook  *workbook  = workbook_new(name);
    lxw_worksheet *worksheet = workbook_add_worksheet(workbook, NULL);
    worksheet_set_paper(worksheet, 9);
    worksheet_set_landscape(worksheet);
    workbook_read_only_recommended(workbook);
```

Comment: Supply the full path name of the file.